# "The file is not eligible for Reference Checking and was not processed"

Tags: publishers

While submitting a paper to a journal of a famous publisher, the submission system added the following link in the top of my PDF file: "Click here to view linked References". When I clicked the link, I got to a page that says  "The file '[my-file].pdf' is not eligible for Reference Checking and was not processed."

How can I make my PDF file eligible for reference checking?

Comment: Check this: https://help.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/904/related/1/p/8045

Comment: @matinking ah, I see. So this feature only works for Microsoft-Word files.

Comment: Probably... Although, there are some typesetting systems, are which even to able to trace the faulty references within the `LaTeX` files, such as wrong bibliographical references...

Comment: I declared the resolving point as an answer, to let the thread be finalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applied references within your document might be faulty. This case is something common regarding the `MS Word` documents. But one could confront with such stuff even within working with `LaTeX`, where the references to some entry (tables, equations, bibliography etc) are not valid.

Hence, one could assert that you better check the document referencing.

More elaborated illustrations could be found [here](https://help.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/904/related/1/p/8045/%22here%22).

Comment: Can the submitted paper be returned to me?